# /.bashrc giving error when opening or logging in to user

Tags: bash, hadoop, installation, hive, ubuntu-14.04

I have a user hduser and installed hadoop and hive on it and I also edited /.bashrc file to set environments but it somehow happens that whenever I try to run /.bashrc or log in to hduser I get the following error

`No command 'Set' found, did you mean:
 Command 'fet' from package 'fet' (universe)
 Command 'net' from package 'samba-common-bin' (main)
 Command 'eet' from package 'libeet-bin' (universe)
Set: command not found`

[this](https://docs.google.com/document/d/164pjttO4wIt1vGhK09ld95g7jC_U1OsTwAmye1PWfvU/edit?usp=sharing) is my /.bashrc file. I am on local machine so I also have access to root

Comment: Shell commands are case-sensitive; you mean lowercase `set`. Voting to close as typo; not really on-topic here, either.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're missing a comment character here:

```
Set Hadoop-related environment variables
```

Should be

```
# Set Hadoop-related environment variables
```